# Como dividir tabela em 4 partes?

Tags: php, tabela-html

Antes de tudo, sim! Já tentei uma outra resposta aqui do site e não resolveu meu problema! Já que eu não estou criando cada `<td>` apenas o primeiro como no código a baixo!

Até agora consegui listar todas uma do lado da outra, mas não identifiquei como fazer essa quebra de linha após 4 resultados!

Esta é minha tabela!

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<tbody align="center">
    @php $i=1 @endphp
    @foreach($matches as $match)
    <?php
        $PARTIDA = "$match->name";
        $string = explode(' x ', $PARTIDA);
        $s = (count($string)) == 1 ? '0' : count($string) - 1;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td align="center; vertical-align: middle;">
            <small>{{ date('d/m H:i', strtotime($match->reference_date)) }}</small> - <small>{{ $match->championship }}</small><br>
            <small><? echo $string[0]; ?> x <? echo $string[$s]; ?></small><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="match[{{$i}}][0]" value="{{$match->id}}">
            <img src="{{ \App\Http\Controllers\MatchController::getShield(1, $match->name) }}" width="50px" class="img-responsive inline-block" />
            <input type="number" name="match[{{$i}}][1]" id="input" class="placares input-sms" required="required">
            &nbsp;&nbsp; VS &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="number" name="match[{{$i}}][2]" id="input" class="placares input-sms" required="required">
            <img src="{{ \App\Http\Controllers\MatchController::getShield(2, $match->name) }}" width="50px" class="img-responsive inline-block" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    @php $i++ @endphp
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

[IMAGEM DA TABELA ATUALMENTE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0L7F.jpg)

COMO POSSO DEIXAR ELA DESSA FORMA?

[IMAGEM DO RESULTADO ESPERADO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a1FZ.jpg)

Comment: olá Dinho, sugiro usar algo melhor para diagramar... está tentando fazer coisas para os quais a tabela não foi feita... isso seria simples substituindo a tabela/td por `<div>`, com o a propriedade `display: flex;` por exemplo, dai basta ajustar a largura fixa da um elemente que "contém" todas as outras divs para que caiba 4 por linha... algo mais assim: `<div class="pai"><div class="filha"></div><div class="filha"></div>......</div>`e no css `.pai { width: 410px } .filha {width: 50px; display: flex }`

Comment: Solução.

No meu caso aparentemente é impossível fazer o que desejo com <table> o correto seria usar <ul>.

Comment: @RicardoPontual Já tinha tentado com <div> também! Apenas <ul> funcionou!

Answer (score -1):

SOLUÇÃO!

```
@php $i=1 @endphp @foreach($matches as $match)
<?php
    $PARTIDA = "$match->name";
    $string = explode(' x ', $PARTIDA);
    $s = (count($string)) == 1 ? '0' : count($string) - 1;
?>
<ul align="center" class="disposicao4">
    <li align="center; vertical-align: middle;">
        <small>{{ date('d/m H:i', strtotime($match->reference_date)) }}</small> - <small>{{ $match->championship }}</small><br>
        <small><? echo $string[0]; ?> x <? echo $string[$s]; ?></small><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="match[{{$i}}][0]" value="{{$match->id}}">
        <img src="{{ \App\Http\Controllers\MatchController::getShield(1, $match->name) }}" width="30px" class="img-responsive inline-block" />
        <input type="number" name="match[{{$i}}][1]" id="input" class="placares input-sms" required="required">
        VS 
        <input type="number" name="match[{{$i}}][2]" id="input" class="placares input-sms" required="required">
        <img src="{{ \App\Http\Controllers\MatchController::getShield(2, $match->name) }}" width="30px" class="img-responsive inline-block" />
    </li>
</ul> @php $i++ @endphp @endforeach
```

CSS

```
ul.disposicao4 {float: right; /* flutuar para o lado desejado */width: 50%; /* ajustar largura desejada */} ul.disposicao4 li {display: block;float: left;width: 100%;}
```